# Cost of "Disrupting Touch" ability if player has Edge in both Speed and Might?

Tags: numenera, cypher-system

Disrupting Touch is an ability that can only be used when the player has already declared a use of the "Phase Sprint" ability. The Player's Handbook states for Phase Sprint:

> Note that some of your other special abilities enable specific
>   actions that you can take while using Phase Sprint. For instance, when
>   using Disrupting Touch, you can make one touch attack while moving...

and for Phase Sprint

> You can turn your Phase Sprint into a melee attack by purposefully
>   grazing another creature as you run.

The character in question has an Edge of 1 in Speed and an Edge of 1 in Might.

So the question is, are these played in combat as two actions, or one, and how is the cost paid? Is it:

1. Phase Sprint is action 1 which costs 0 because of Speed Edge; Disrupting Touch can't be done till next turn, but also costs 0 because of Might Edge; 
   Phase Sprint continues until the attack is made.
2. Phase Sprint is declared as an action, and its cost is zero (1 Edge in Speed), then Disrupting Touch is declared as a modification to the action but its cost is 1 Might (because Edge was already used during this turn). Phase Sprint ends at the end of the turn (in sync with the attack).
3. Phase Sprint is declared as an action, and its cost is zero (1 Edge in Speed), then Disrupting Touch is declared as a modification to the action and its cost is zero (because of 1 Edge in Might). Phase Sprint ends in sync with the attack at the end of the turn.

The player would, of course, prefer #2, but we'd all prefer to be sure we applied the system's rules properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Numenera Discovery, p.23:

> When something requires you to spend points from a stat Pool, your
>   Edge for that stat reduces the cost.

and p.23

> These abilities are called enablers. Using one of these abilities is
>   not considered an action. Enablers either function constantly [...] or
>   happen as part of another action

So: Phase Sprint is declared as an action, and its cost is zero (1 Edge in Speed), then Disrupting Touch is declared as a modification to the action and its cost is zero (because of 1 Edge in Might). Phase Sprint ends in sync with the attack at the end of the turn.